# Shouldn't this javascript animation produce a sine wave movement?

Tags: javascript, animation, trigonometry

I am doing a small JavaScript animation hoping that the little `div` can move along a sine wave, and for the moment the horizontal path works fine (just straight line). I am almost sure that my math formula for the `Y` axis is wrong. I have tried to correct it with some examples I found, but none of them worked for me. In all the possibilities I tried, the `Y` axis is ignored and the little box just moves in straight line horizontally.

How can I fix this, so the movement goes along a sine wave? I know that it's possible to do it easier with jQuery or using html 5, but I just got wondering what is wrong in my original code... I would prefer to fix this if possible.

```
function animate() {
    xnow = item.style.left;
    item.style.left = parseInt(xnow)+1+'px';
    ynow = item.style.top;
    item.style.top = ynow + (Math.sin((2*Math.PI*xnow)/document.width))*document.heigth;
    setTimeout(animate,20); 
}
```

The complete code here:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twNcy/)

Comment: This doesn't fix your issue, but `height` is misspelled as `heigth`, also if you log the output of `item.style.top` the value is always 400px.

Comment: ops...thanks :-) I misspelled. Anyways, that's what I don't understand, why the value doesn't change...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.width

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3Auwh/35/

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-accurate-timers-in-javascript/ might be interesting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see several problems with your code:

- `xnow` contains a string in this format: `###px` You cannot multiply it, so use `parseInt()` in your `Math.sin()` call.
- Same goes for your code to grab `ynow`, it needs `parseInt()`.
- Better is to use other (global) variables to store the x and y coordinates as numbers. And add `px` when you update coordinates of the div-element.
- When you multiply `2*Math.PI` with `xnow` (which contains only integer numbers), the `sin()` function will always return `0`. So you won't get a sine-like movement. You need to divide `xnow` by the number of x-steps you want to use to do a complete sine-like movement
- `Math.sin()` returns a value between -1 and +1, so you need to multiply it by an amplitude to see a (more clear) effect.

To keep it as much as you designed it, it would become something like this (takes 50 x-movement steps to do a complete sine and uses an amplitude of 10 pixels):

```
function animate() {
    xnow = parseInt(item.style.left);
    item.style.left = (xnow+1)+'px';
    ynow = parseInt(item.style.top);
    item.style.top = (ynow+Math.sin(2*Math.PI*(xnow/50))*10) + "px";
    setTimeout(animate,20);
}
```

As mentioned: it is much better to use some global variables containing the values (instead of using `parseInt()` all the time)

See my [updated JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/twNcy/5/).

Comment: Not sure if I understand your last point. Do you mean something like this?: `(Math.sin(2*Math.PI*(xnow/parseInt(document.body.clientWidth)))*document.height`

Answer (score 7):

A sin function is in the form of y = a * sin(b*x) + c, where c is the y-midpoint of the function (or the horizontal line across which the function oscillates), where a is the amplitude (maximal y-offset from y = c) and b is the period (number of x = 2*pi segments per wave).

Given that, and that we know a sin wave oscillates from -a to +a, we know our offset (c) should 1) be constant and 2) halfway between our upper and lower bounds. For this we can use

`c  = document.height / 2;`

Your amplitude will be the same value as c, if you want the object to traverse the entire screen. On testing you will find that this makes it go past the bottom of the page, so let's just make it 90%.

`a = 0.9 * c;`

For a period of 1 for the entire page, you'll need to make b multiply x by a factor such that it will be the fraction of 2*pi. In this case

`b = 2*Math.PI/document.width;`

On each iteration, there is no need to get the value of `ynow`, it is a function of `xnow`. You can do something along the lines of

`xnow = parseInt(item.top.left) + 5;`

Then calculate the new y with

`ynow = c + a * Math.sin(b * xnow);`.

Then set the style of the item.

`item.style.left = xnow + 'px';`

`item.style.top = ynow + 'px';`

Let me know if anything was unclear. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `parseInt()` on `xnow`. You also need to add 'px' to the end of the of the number to make into a correctly formatted string.

This code works:

```
function animate() {
  xnow = parseInt(item.style.left);
  item.style.left = xnow+1+'px';
  item.style.top = 200 + (Math.sin((2*Math.PI*xnow)/200))*document.height+'px';
  setTimeout(animate,20); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple errors:

- `height` is misspelled
- Parse `xnow` as an int before taking the sine
- Parse `ynow` as an int before adding it (though it's not actually necessary, see below)
- Add `"px"` to the end of the assignment to `item.style.top`
- The equation could use some tweaking:

I suggest starting with `(400 + Math.sin(2*Math.PI*xnow/document.width) * 200) + "px"` and then playing around with it. The `400` is the horizontal axis to base the sine wave on. If you use `ynow` instead of a constant, you get cumulative effects (the wave will be much taller than you intend or the horizontal axis will change over time).

`document.width` is the width of one full period. The `200` is the peak amplitude (distance from the horizontal to a peak - `document.height` would push the box off screen in both directions). Plug in this function in place of the current one and then you can play around with the numbers:

```
function animate() {
  xnow = parseInt(item.style.left);
  item.style.left = xnow+1+'px';
  item.style.top = (400 + Math.sin(2*Math.PI*xnow/document.width) * 200) + "px";
  setTimeout(animate,20); 
}
```